# SSRS Report in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

Hello can you Please Provide me the Link for SSRS Report in MS CRM 2011.Please Provide me Link where can i learn step by step SSRS Report for CRM 2011.I have searched but i dont get any link that give me step by step information...

Comment: Here you can find a step by step: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/10/26/how-to-creating-custom-report-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-bids-fetch-extension.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The CRM documentation has everything you could want to know about creating reports:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097

Note, for CRM Online, FetchXML is your only option; On-prem, you can choose SQL queries or FetchXML.  I favor SQL for it ease of development.